# Can't open usb device via webUSB

Tags: angular, webusb

I need to connect the device to the browser using the webUSB, after the connection I call the open method and this error falls "**Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Access denied.**". How to fix it?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const button = document.getElementById('connectButton');
    button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      let device;
      try {
        device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: []});
      } catch (err) {
      }

      device.open()
        .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1))
        .then(() => device.claimInterface(device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you running on?

On Linux you will get this error if the current user doesn't have permission to open the USB device. You will need to configure a udev rule to allow the user to access it.

On Windows you will get this error if the WinUSB driver is not loaded for the device. You can use the [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) tool to force Windows to load a particular driver for the device.

The error messages given to the site are intentionally vague. Check chrome://device-log to see more details about the error the browser encountered trying to open the device.

Comment: Any links or details on how to add a proper udev rule? Something like this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/15570/configure-udev-to-change-permissions-on-usb-hid-device